# I deployed my Spring boot application in Linux server but I am not able to save the file in server.I am getting below error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jboss, spring-batch

'/home/jboss/MandhanFileUpload/11226.txt (No such file or directory)

My application.properties are like

uploadPath.location=/home/jboss/MandhanFileUpload/

Comment: what is the error message? Where are the logs?

Comment: No such file or directory... it's showing in the console. But folders are present in server

Comment: More information will be needed. What does your code look like? Does that directory actually exist? Do you have write permission to it?

Comment: Are you trying to write the file inside your application?   If so that is specifically forbidden.    Does the user that is executing the app have permissions to folder /home/jboss/MandhanFileUpload?

Comment: Actually how are you trying to write this out?   It sounds like it is looking for file 11226.txt to already exist?